# pcolormesh in polar coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the probability density of wave functions for the H-atom with matplotlib. I managed to do it in cartesian coordinates, but for later calculations it will be better, if I specify psi in polar coordinates. Now I am trying to make the plot work, but it gives the wrong results (the axis lines of the plots should be cartesian coordinates though). Any idea how to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
from scipy import integrate


Z = 1
a_0 = 1
pi = np.pi


n = 300
r = np.linspace(-10, 10, n) 
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, n) 
R, Theta = np.meshgrid(r, theta) 


def psi(r,theta):
    return 1/(4*sqrt(2*pi))*(Z/a_0)**(3/2) * Z*r/a_0*np.exp(-Z*r/(2*a_0))*np.cos(theta)


X1 = R*np.cos(Theta)
X2 = R*np.sin(Theta)

plt.pcolormesh(X1,X2,psi(R,Theta)**2)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Incorrect output:

[image: Incorrect output]

If I calculate it in cartesian coordinates I get what I want:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.cm as cm 
from scipy import integrate


Z = 1
a_0 = 1
pi = np.pi


n = 300
x1 = np.linspace(-10, 10, n) 
x2 = np.linspace(-10,10, n) 
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1,x2) 


def r(x,y):
    return sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

def psi(x,y):
    return 1/(4*sqrt(2*pi))*(Z/a_0)**(3/2) * Z*r(x,y)/a_0*np.exp(-Z*r(x,y)/(2*a_0))*x/r(x,y)



plt.pcolormesh(X1,X2,psi(X1,X2)**2)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: correct output]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "wrong result"? You can add a new polar axis by using `fig=plt.figure();ax=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar');ax.pocolormesh(R, Theta, psi(R,Theta)**2)`. You can write all the statements separated by `;` on different lines. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: @ChristophTerasa: Maybe your comment is in the right direction, but I am not sure since addin your code gives me only empty polar axes. I tried to make clear in my original post, what I mean by "correct result".

Comment: I found the cause and posted a solution below.

Answer (score 5):

The radius in polar coordinates is wrong, because it is negative, and this in turn makes your calculation of psi in polar coordinates fail. Simply change

```
r = np.linspace(-10, 10, n)
```

to

```
r = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
```

to solve your issue.
[image]